# jenkins - location for additional jar files and tools

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, ant, classpath

I'm trying to set up a build process for jenkins. The build process (based on ant) calls a class from a jar file (i.e. saxon.jar). This jar file is not included in die SCM.

What's the best location for storing additional jar files/tools in jenkins?

How do I tell jenkins where the jar can be found (classpath)?

Thanks, aronadaal

Comment: Why don't you use some kind of artifactory like maven repo for downloading the dependencies?

Comment: Check out the use of Apache ivy to manage your project's dependencies, downloading them automatically as part of the build process from a Maven repository